# C++ writing to text using buffer returns non ascii character at end of file.

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new with C++ and am trying to read and write binary file. I have used the read and write functions to read text from one file and output it to a new file. However the following characters always appear at the end of the created text file "ÌÌ". Is a particular character indicating the end of file being saved in the character buffer?

```
int main(){
ifstream myfile("example.txt", ios::ate);
ofstream outfile("new.txt"); 
ifstream::pos_type size; 
char buf [1024]; 

if(myfile.is_open()){       
    size=myfile.tellg(); 
    cout<<"The file's size is "<<(int) size<<endl;
    myfile.seekg(0,ios::beg);
    while(!myfile.eof()){
        myfile.read(buf, sizeof(buf)); 
    }
    outfile.write(buf,size); 
    }
else 
    cout<<"Error"<<endl;

myfile.close();
outfile.close();
cin.get();
return 0;

}
```

Comment: If you use `eof()`, you don't understand how to use iostreams. Please read the reference documentation until you understand what each part of your code does. It's all documented, but you have to read it and cannot just guess what might happen.

Comment: Should also note that using `close()` is completely unnecessary in C++ because of RAII.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the only problem with your code (try it on a file bigger than 1024 bytes) but since you are doing binary I/O you need

```
ifstream myfile("example.txt", ios::ate|ios::binary);
ofstream outfile("new.txt", ios::binary);
```

Comment: Right - because a text file will lose characters as it's read, the final count won't be the same as the `tellg` indicated.

Comment: The buffer will only hold 1kb, but I was thinking of splitting larger files in order to eventually send it in a socket. (Specifying  ios::binary did remove the strange characters at the end)